# Set session value in foreach loop

Tags: php, session, pdo, foreach

In the project, I am working on at the moment. Users can upload pictures in different parts of the site. Either they could upload pictures in a post they posted or they could upload pictures to show off their pet (which has a profile page already). So I came up with an images table, which looks like this:

```
TABLE `images` (
 `image_id` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'FOREIGN KEY referencing the user_id of the user, who uploaded the images',
 `image_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
 `dog_pet_id` INT(11) NULL COMMENT 'FOREIGN KEY referencing the pet's, who this image belongs to',
 `post_id` INT(11) NULL COMMENT 'FOREIGN KEY referencing the post's, who this image belongs to',
 PRIMARY KEY (`image_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

So if the user with the user_id = 1, would have a pet with the dog_pet_id = 2 and he would upload a picture for this pet the output would look like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| | image_id | user_id | image_name | dog_pet_id | post_id | |
| |        1 |       1 |     bla    |       2    |       0 | |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If he would upload an image in a post the dog_pet_id would be 0 and the post_id would have the post's id and so on.
All this works as intended. **My problem is displaying these images!**
**My attempt to solve the problem** (in a MVC structure (no CMS or framework)):
I would like to display just those images where the user_id is equal to the user's user_id and the dog_pet_id is equal to the pet's id. The problem, I am not able to solve is **how to get the pet's dog_pet_id from the view to the model**.
Usually I did things like this using a form submit or some kind of link, with which I could send the id but this is the first time I cannot do that.
Therefore, my idea was to send it via the $_SESSION super global, however, this always gets overwritten in my foreach loop. So if there is more than one pet per user, only the last pet's images will be diplayed.
**The Model**

```
    /**
     * Display the pet images, which have been uploaded by the user
     */
    public static function displayPetImages()
    {
        $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

        $query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE user_id = :user_id AND dog_pet_id = :dog_pet_id");

        $query->execute(array(':user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'], ':dog_pet_id' => $_SESSION['dog_pet_id']));

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
```

**The Controller**

```
    /**
     * Show user's PRIVATE profile
     */
    public function showProfile()
    {
        'pets' => PetModel::getPet(), // get's the pet's information from the database
        'petImages' => PetModel::displayPetImages() // is the function shown above
        ));
    }
```

**The View**

```
foreach ($this->pets as $pet) {
    foreach ($this->petImages as $petImage) { ?>
          $_SESSION['dog_pet_id'] = $pet->dog_pet_id; <----- This is always overwritten!
          <img src="<?= /path/to/the/image/ . $pet->dog_pet_id . '/' . $petImage->image_name . '.jpg' ?>" />
     }
    echo "<form action='" . Config::get('URL') . 'pet/uploadPetImages_action/' . $pet->dog_pet_id . "' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
    echo "<input type='file' name='images[]' multiple required />";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='5242880' />";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Upload Images' />";
    echo "</form>
    }
```

I am not even sure, if what I would like to achieve is at all possible or if there probably even is a better way to do this.
Anyway, I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

**UPDATE**
**The Model**

```
    /**
     * Display the pet images, which have been uploaded by the user
     */
    public static function displayPetImages($dog_pet_id)
    {
        $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

        $query = $database->prepare("SELECT image_name FROM images WHERE user_id = :user_id AND dog_pet_id = :dog_pet_id");

        $query->execute(array(':user_id' => Session::get('user_id'), ':dog_pet_id' => $dog_pet_id));

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
```

**The Controller**

```
        /**
         * Show user's PRIVATE profile
         */
        public function showProfile()
        {
            'pets' => PetModel::getPet(), // get's the pet's information from the database
            'petImages' => PetModel::displayPetImages() // is the function shown above
            ));
        }
```

**The View**

```
foreach ($this->pets as $pet) { ?>          
        <?php foreach ($this->petImages as $petImage) { ?>
            <img src="<?= Config::get('URL') . Config::get('PATH_IMAGES_PUBLIC') . Session::get('user_id') . '/' . 'pets/' . $pet->dog_pet_id . '/' . displayPetImages($pet->dog_pet_id) . '.jpg' ?>" />;
        }
     }
```

**Output**

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for PetModel::displayPetImages() 
>   Notice: Undefined variable: dog_pet_id

Comment: Can you add the code where a user would submit the view to the backend?

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Display the pet images, which have been uploaded by the user
 */
public static function displayPetImages($dog_pet_id)
{
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

    $query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE user_id = :user_id AND dog_pet_id = :dog_pet_id");

    $query->execute(array(':user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'], ':dog_pet_id' => $dog_pet_id));

// return only image name

}
```

Pass pet id to function and use it in query.

also change output of function. it should return only image name.

and in view call this function directly like this

```
foreach ($this->pets as $pet) {
foreach ($this->petImages as $petImage) { ?>
      //$_SESSION['dog_pet_id'] = $pet->dog_pet_id; <----- This is always overwritten!
      <img src="<?= /path/to/the/image/ . $pet->dog_pet_id . '/' . displayPetImages($pet->dog_pet_id)  ?>" />
 }
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! At the moment I am getting undefined variable error for 'dog_pet_id' in the model. I tried to change it to `PetModel::displayPetImages($pet->dog_pet_id)` that did not solve it either.

Comment: Your answer looks very promising. This is exactly what I would like to achieve. The only problem is that I cannot get your code to work. I tried passing the $dog_pet_id variable to the controller function and then to the model but that did not work either. If you could help me over this last hurdle I would be beyond thankful!

Comment: i just explain idea. this code not tested... you need to modify as per need.

Comment: kringeltorte. please make sure your function start like this ... public static function displayPetImages($dog_pet_id) {  }

Comment: Thank you! I checked that. It does start like that. However, I cannot call it from within the <img src="">.

Comment: you can call it in image tag. you need to return image name from model.  here where i put comment .. // return only image name

Comment: I updated my question! This is how my code looks at the moment! In my opinion this code does exactly what I want, if `displayPetImages($pet->dog_pet_id)` would call the displayPetImages() function.

Comment: you no need to call function in controller. 'petImages' => PetModel::displayPetImages()  ..  here you need to call other function which will return all pet images. for specific user. and in view you can do loop to get individual images.

Comment: I see your point! However, even if i leave the controller completely out I am not able to call the function from the view. If I call it like I usally would `PetModel::displayPetImages($pet->dog_pet_id)` it does not work. I tried everything. With " or ' without it etc. But you already helped me trmendously!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

That session thing won't work, for the reason you specify: as your view runs that loop, it overwrites the variable.

I'd have a separate HTML form for each pet, and a separate upload button;

```
<?php foreach ($this->pets as $pet) { ?>
    <form action="/wherever" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="pet_id" value="<?= $pet->pet_id ?>" />
        <?php foreach ($this->petImages as $petImage) { ?>
            <img src="<?= /path/to/the/image/.$pet->dog_pet_id.'/'.$petImage->image_name.'.jpg' ?>" />
        <?php } ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Then depending on which Save button they click, it will have a different `pet_id` value for you to compare.

Comment: I really like your answer because this is what I am used to doing! However, I do not 100% understand what you are saying. Could you elaborate on how to use this in the model then? Would I not have to always click the save button before viewing the pictures? I am sorry, I am really new to all of this...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should work for you on submitting an array of all pet ids.

```
foreach( $this->pets as $pet ):
    echo "<form action='" . Config::get('URL') . 'pet/uploadPetImages_action/' . $pet->dog_pet_id . "' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
    ?>
    <?php foreach( $this->petImages as $petImage ): ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="pets[<?php echo $pet->dog_pet_id; ?>]" value="pets[<?php echo $pet->dog_pet_id; ?>]" />
        <img src="<?php echo '/path/to/the/image/' . $pet->dog_pet_id . '/' . $petImage->image_name . '.jpg'; ?>" />
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    echo "<input type='file' name='images[]' multiple required />";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='5242880' />";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Upload Images' />";
    echo "</form>";
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am not sure how this solves my problem. When I submit the pictures there is no problem in getting the pet's id. When I am watching the pet's profile page that is where I have the problem getting the pet's id. Although, I might misunderstand your answer since I am very new to all this..